# How to add spaces in the given string

Tags: c

This is what I've tried. I just want to add spaces between each character of the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char a[] = "123456";
    puts(a);
    int len;
    len = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == ' ')
        {
            a[i] == ''   
            //for (int j = i; j < len; j++)
            //
            //    a[j]=a[j+1];
            //    //a[j+1]='*';
        }
    }
    puts(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to add spaces between each character, and save the result in a new string? Or do you want to simply print the string, but with spaces between each character?

Comment: This is one of those homeworks that require you to _write it out on paper FIRST_, and only then try coding it. (Almost _all_ programming tasks require you to solve the problem first, before writing code.)

Comment: A hint would be to iterate with `for (int i = 0; a[i]; i++)`. Your `len` is actually **size** that includes the `'\0'` character. To determine whether to output a space, you can do `if (i) putchar(' ');` before `putchar(a[i]);`. You cannot add to `a` as you have only declared storage for 7-characters (all of which you have used). You would need to double the size of `a` to add spaces to it. (actually you would need another `length - 1` characters to be exact). But, *Don't Skimp on Buffer Size*, so `a[16] = "123456";` (or 32) would be fine.

Comment: Actually, I would amend that. Presuming you declare, at minimum, `char a[12]`, starting from the end, e.g. `size_t len = strlen(a);` and then looping `while (len--) {` will allow you to include a space between each character. (don't forget the new *nul-terminating* character `a[2 * len - 1] = 0;`.

Comment: thanks to all of you. I kind of got the idea of what you(David C. Rankin
) are suggesting. But still can't understand. How about you give me a written code.

Comment: We will not do your homework, learn by doing yourself. Apply the suggestions, experiment with them, don't forget to raise the warning level of the compiler to the maximum, correct your code until all errors and warnings are gone. If you still cannot get the expected result, [edit] your question and **add** the new code. Please don't delete the old code, as it would render the comments useless.

Comment: What if you do `size_t len = strlen (a);` and then nul-terminate at `a[2 * len - 1] = 0;` and then loop `for (size_t i = len - 1; i; i--) {` and then you only need two statements (1) to move the current character to index twice the current value of `i` and then (2) add a space at the index one less than that. When the loop completes you will `puts(a)` and get `"1 2 3 4 5 6"`. Think about it this way. If `'6'` was at index `i` (e.g. `i == 5`) when the loop starts, what do you have to do to `i` to move it to index `10`?